# system design vs system architecture

Tags: architecture, system-design

I have seen many examples of system designs.
For example, design a URL shortener for Twitter in *Grokking the System Design Interview*.

But then, what is system architecture?

Are those two the same things?

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same, but they are related.

System design is the process when you try to come up with a viable solution (or multiple ones) based on the provided requirements. You tries to specify smaller components with well-defined responsibilities. Also you define how (and when) they are interacting with each other.

System architecture is the artifact of the former process. It captures how did you divide the problem space into smaller chunks and how your components as a whole try to solve the original big problem.

---

**UPDATE #1**: Provide example

In order to better illustrate the differences let me provide you a super simplified example.

#### Context

Let's suppose you have a bunch of microservices and some of them are abused sometimes. During resource abuse the service becomes slow and unresponsive.

In order to mitigate this, business decides to introduce rate limiting.

#### Design

*The steps are reduced and simplified to ease understanding*.

1. Clarify with the business whether they meant request queueing or throttling
2. Agree on terminology to prefer rate limiting over throttling
3. Do some research about industry standard algorithms and data structures
4. Make a comparison between **leaky bucket** and **token bucket**
5. Check whether there is an existing solution which can be used in a way that satisfies all requirements
6. Decide which endpoints should be protected
7. Document your finding and decisions

#### Artifacts

- One or multiple [Proof of concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) to verify all requirements can be met with the chosen library/libraries
- An [Architecture Decision Record](https://adr.github.io/) to capture which library should be used in which programming language in case of rate limiting
- Another ADR to document how should clients handle rate limitation

  - For example: they should retry the request if they have received 429 response code and respect the *retry-after* header
- Update(s) on the architecture diagram(s) to indicate which services utilize rate limiting

  - Or an introduction of an API gateway to have a centralized place for common concerns
- A specification how to setup the rate limiting rules

  - Like: 100 reqs / min, 1 000 reqs / hours

---

**UPDATE #2**: Reflect to the OP's example

> Suppose I am designing **tinyUrl**, if I am doing system design, I will do the followings:
>
> 1. I collect requirements
> 2. I will check the estimation of usage such as traffic and bandwidth
> 3. based on this, I can have a database schema,
> 4. I will check the storage based on the database schema
> 5. I will create API for my system
> 6. create abstract system flow ex) client -> application -> server -> database
> 7. consider data partitioning and replication to accommodate latency, availability and reliability
> 8. check possible cache usage
> 9. lastly, do bit more detailed data flow within the system. For example, use load balancing.
>
> Same example with system architecture would be more about implementation detail what kind of technology I will choose to use?

As I said before system design is the process whereas system architecture is the outcome of the design process. What you have described is the process, which may/may not include technology selection.

- In case of a component related feature design you might want to include the suggested technologies/libraries as well in your system architecture
- In case of an integration design you will focus more on the communication protocols, edge cases, security and so on ...

Let me try to capture the difference from another angle. Whenever you design a solution for a particular problem then you explore different alternatives and try to choose wisely based on the requirements. Your proposed architecture captures your designs to be able to reason about the system. But this is a living thing. It can change over time as new requirements come in.

Comment: So, system design is more about explaining step by step approach, whereas system architecture is about the whole process of how input/data/output flow within the system in the big picture. I am still not sure if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @YaldaHami System design is the process,  whereas the system architecture is the result / outcome / artifact of the design process. In other words you capture your design decisions in your system architecture. Does it make sense?

Comment: I am sorry, but It is a bit hard for me to draw a picture of what the system architecture would be. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NMg6yFJrlQ Can I imagine it something like the video?

Comment: @YaldaHami Later today I will update my post to include an example.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your time. 
I think this video is much more relevant in the context of cs. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScbSrUSbumo&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60jIMmB53zl6awCKMnABhYx&index=14&t=187s

Comment: @YaldaHami I have updated my post please revisit it

Comment: @YaldaHami Did my example bring clarity?

Comment: Thank you for following up. I am sorry for the late reply. Yes, your example certainly helped me. But, I would like to confirm once again if my understanding if correct with my example. Suppose I am designing tinyUrl, if I am doing system design, I will do the following, 1) I collect requirements, 2) I will check the estimation of usage such as traffic and bandwidth 3) based on this, I can have a database schema, 4) I will check the storage based on the database schema 5) I will create API for my system 6) create abstract system flow ex) client -> application -> server -> database

Comment: 7) consider data partitioning and replication to accommodate latency, availability and reliability 8) check possible cache usage 9) lastly, do bit more detailed data flow within the system. For example, use load balancing. 

same example with system architecture would be more about implementation detail what kind of technology I will choose to use? 

After I wrote this, I feel like I am still bit confused about system architecture.  Thank you for your time.
@ PeterCsala

Comment: @YaldaHami I've replied to your latest question in my post. Please consider to upvote and/or mark as the answer if you satisfied with it. If you have further questions please let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I was bit busy last couple days, I will work on this one.

Comment: @YaldaHami If my provided description gave you clarity then please consider to accept it as the answer or upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, they're not the same.

Generally speaking, System Design referrs to the component side of thigs. System design includes more low-level design diagrams. Diagrams and documentation that is closer to the code. Usually, for smaller applications, having only system design (without "Architecture") might be enough. Maybe that's the case with the Url shortener that you mentioned. Consider UML as a representation of System Design. However, the term System Design covers more than only that.

When it comes to System Architecture, we're going one level up. Keeping track of System Architecture is absolutely needed for larger, especially multi-service applications, where there are multiple applications talking to each other. Beside services, there might be some other cloud offerings, such as Azure Functions, Queues and Topics for asynchronous communication, different types of data stores, integrations with third parties and so on.

In conclusion, System Architecture is responsible for inter-service communication and coordination. Architecture is about the overall system, which might be made out of multiple components, whereas System Design is the design of a single component in particular, and has more in-depth details and documentations about it.